# What version control system is typically used in Java Enterprise development?

Tags: java-ee, version-control

There are many vcs available. Which of them are typically used in JavaEE world?

Comment: Any decent VCS would work with Java, I don't think the language has special requirements in this regard.

Comment: @Mahmoud Hossam: It depends. For VCSs which store unstructured bytestreams that's true, but not for VCSs which store structured, strongly typed object graphs. They need to understand the syntax and semantics of the programs you are storing in them. The downside is that they only work with one language, the *upside* is that stuff like adding, removing or renaming variables, methods, functions, procedures, fields, objects, classes, modules, traits, packages, mixins, bundles or even large-scale refactorings become just yet another VCS operation, and are thus trivially mergeable or revertable.

Comment: @Jorg But they all work, I didn't say they would all be the same.

Comment: Subversion, Git, Mercurial, any of those can work for you.

Comment: @Jorg are any of those that are commonly used in Java? I've never even heard of one that works that way.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, can you provide some examples of tools like what you describe?

Comment: @Jeremy @Thomas Owens: The one that's built into the Intentional Workbench works that way. Not sure what it's called (or if it even has a name). Monticello works that way. And at least Monticello can *not* be used for Java code (it can *only* be used for Smalltalk code), so @Mahmoud Hossam's claim that "any decent VCS would work with Java" is at least misleading, if not false.

Comment: @Jorg Yes, Smalltalk has its little affectations, I suspected a system like you described would be in one of "those" languages ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are so many doing Java EE development that - regardless of VCS - you will find some place using it if looking long enough.

These days you either have to conform to existing infrastructure, or you go with the VCS with the best support in your chosen IDE.

If you just want to get started using this, then consider using CVS which is simple, and is well-supported in almost all IDE's.  You can then learn how it works, including how to diff an older version etc.

Comment: Don't forget, make sure your CI manager (you are doing continuous integration, aren't you?) supports it as well.

Comment: @TMN, a new learner might not have this in place.  I believe that most CI's support CVS though.

Comment: CVS is a bit moldy.  Branching is slow and painful.  SVN, Git, or Mercurial are far better choices these days.

Comment: @kevin, for an absolute beginner it is nice with things which work out of the box.

Comment: There is no good reason why CVS integration should be in the box with Eclipse, but not Subversion.

Comment: @kevin, probably not, but that is how it is today and that is what I base my suggestion on.  When it changes, the answer can be updated.